# How can I get the query string, starting by the process id associated to the Postgres connection running it (output of htop)?

Tags: postgresql, htop

I have a machine, let's call it `DB_server`, 
which is connected to two application machines, 
let's call them `application_server_1` and `application_server_2`.

`DB_server` hosts 3 postgres databases on it, 
the name of one of it is `centraldb`, 
and the name of one of the users of this db is `central`.

On `DB_server`, by using `htop`, I found out there are some processes run by `postgres` user, associated to some postgres commands (which - if I guess right - are being run by the `application_server_2` connecting to `server_DB` and connecting to the database `centraldb` with user `central`), which consumes a lot of CPU.

Given the following output from `htop`, indicating which is the process consuming a lot of CPU, how can I find out which are the queries which are running on those connections, and thus consuming the CPU of `DB_server`?

```
PID     USER      ...  Command

<pid_1>   postgres  ...  postgres: 10/central centraldb <IP_application_server_2>(<pid_2>) idle
```